# RSpec tests for Evernote API

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails, evernote, vcr

I have a Rails app that makes calls to the Evernote API. I want to write RSpec tests for these calls. What's the best way of doing that? I know I can use Webmock or VCR, but - unless I'm mistaken - I would not then be able to have self-contained tests in my repository without pushing either my secret key or a cached oauth response.

Answer (score 1):

VCR provides a simple way to filter out sensitive data like secret keys:

https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-4-0/docs/configuration/filter-sensitive-data!

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I'm trying out your suggestion but it's taking me some time. I'll come back when I've tried it out.